Wasabi coinjoin and the "Chainalysis demixing"
Learning more about how coinjoin works I came across the tale of how Chainalysis "demixed" a 50 BTC transaction that went through Wasabi (TXID aa8d7407f88dca9b1779880c3d2e3245e02217f7366972d617f812c8dd73a96a). If we ignore all of Chainalysis's PR about being able to crack Wasabi and look at how it actually happened it appears that it was due to address re-use (addresses bc1qxp8k4un9tzkm2phsvs22r26l6l2ny93tnts7nq and bc1qq2cp2swuhkd9serh5h4vhnn00l89e2wjfwyarr) by Wasabi which in turn lead to the identification of a cluster.
Was this just a case of bad practice/a bug in the code on Wasabi's part? Or is there something more to this?
I realise the user did some less than sensible things in the big picture, but I'm more wanting to focus on the technical side in relation to Wasabi.
